# Python extend method of parent class

Tags: python, google-app-engine, super, polymodel

I'm writing a Google Appengine app in Python. The app does receive and send data through google cloud endpoint messages. Below you'll find an example of the database model definition. Object contains all the objects, ObjectBoolean just the boolean ones and ObjectInteger just the integer ones. All the classes do have got two methods defined: message_to_model() and model_to_message().

How can I re-use the methods in the sub-classes? I do want to get rid of repeated code like:

```
        self.name = request.name
        self.description = request.description
        self.created = request.created
        self.modified = request.modified
```

Those fields are part of the Object-class. But in my code the fields are also listed in the sub-classes, which is what I do want to avoid. How can I achieve this? I did already check the super() function, but I think this is not suitable in my case because I do not want to execute the method I do want to extend it.

Cheers

-Luca.

```
from google.appengine.ext.ndb import polymodel
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from endpoint_messages.object import *


class Object(polymodel.PolyModel):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True, verbose_name="Name")
    description = ndb.TextProperty(verbose_name="Description")
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Created")
    modified = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Modified")

    def model_to_message(self):
        return ObjectResponseMessage(class_name=self._class_name(),
                                     id=self.key.integer_id(),
                                     name=self.name,
                                     description=self.description,
                                     created=self.created,
                                     modified=self.modified)

    def message_to_model(self, request):
        self.name = request.name
        self.description = request.description
        self.created = request.created
        self.modified = request.modified


class ObjectBoolean(Object):
    current = ndb.BooleanProperty(verbose_name="Current")
    target = ndb.BooleanProperty(verbose_name="Target")

    def model_to_message(self):
        return ObjectResponseMessage(class_name=self._class_name(),
                                     id=self.key.integer_id(),
                                     name=self.name,
                                     description=self.description,
                                     created=self.created,
                                     modified=self.modified,
                                     boolean=ObjectBooleanMessage(current=self.current,
                                                                  target=self.target))

    def message_to_model(self, request):
        self.name = request.name
        self.description = request.description
        self.created = request.created
        self.modified = request.modified
        if request.boolean:
            self.current = request.boolean.success
            self.target = request.boolean.target


class ObjectInteger(Object):
    current = ndb.IntegerProperty(verbose_name="Current")
    target = ndb.IntegerProperty(verbose_name="Target")

    def model_to_message(self):
        return ObjectResponseMessage(class_name=self._class_name(),
                                     id=self.key.integer_id(),
                                     name=self.name,
                                     description=self.description,
                                     created=self.created,
                                     modified=self.modified,
                                     float=ObjectIntegerMessage(current=self.current,
                                                                target=self.target))

    def message_to_model(self, request):
        self.name = request.name
        self.description = request.description
        self.created = request.created
        self.modified = request.modified
        if request.integer:
            self.current = request.integer.current
            self.target = request.integer.target
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`super()` can be used for this. You could use something like this in `ObjectBoolean`:

```
def message_to_model(self, request):
    super(ObjectBoolean, self).message_to_model(request)

    if request.boolean:
        self.current = request.boolean.success
        self.target = request.boolean.target
```

For this to work, `Object` must be a new style class, which it is if `polymodel.PolyModel` is a new style class.

Comment: Hi spkersten, thanks a lot. It seems like polymodel.PolyModel is a new style class. I did add the code as you described and it did work. What about model_to_message()? Is it also possible there with "return"? Or would I have to rewrite it to store a part of a message?

Comment: If you can pass an ObjectBooleanMessage to ObjectReposeMessage in another way the via the constructor, you can again use super to call Object.model_to_message, add your ObjectBooleanMessage to the result and then return it. Alternatively, you can give Object.model_to_message a second kwargs parameter and pass those argument on to ObjectBooleanMessage. ObjectBoolean.message_to_model can then call Object.model_to_message with a keyword argument: boolean=ObjectBooleanMessage(...)